# Rails 4 ActionMailer Sending Email With Name not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am having trouble testing my mailer. It appears assigning attributes [:to, :from, :reply_to] with a email in the format described as [email-with-name](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-with-name) doesn't work.

## Here is a simple example.

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def simple
      mail(
        from: "Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>",
        to: "Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>",
        reply_to: "Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>"
      )
    end
end
```

## message_mailer_spec.rb

```
EXPECTED = "Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>"

describe MessageMailer do
  before do
    @email = MessageMailer.simple
  end

  it "expect `from` to eq #{EXPECTED}" do
    expect( @email.from ).to eq(EXPECTED)
  end

  it "expect `to` to eq #{EXPECTED}" do
    expect( @email.to ).to eq(EXPECTED)
  end

  it "expect `reply_to` to eq #{EXPECTED}" do
    expect( @email.reply_to ).to eq(EXPECTED)
  end
end
```

## Test results all the same

```
1) MessageMailer expect `reply_to` to eq Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>

  Failure/Error: expect( @email.reply_to ).to eq(EXPECTED)

    expected: "Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>"
        got: ["aaron@test.com"]

   (compared using ==)
```

Anyone know how to assign [to:, from:, reply_to:] in the email-with-name format?

Am I missing something?

Are there different methods that hold the email headers that I can test against?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I got it by testing against the header hash of the email.

This is how to test the values of 'from', 'reply_to' and 'to' in rspec.

```
describe MessageMailer do
  before do
    @email = MessageMailer.simple
  end

  it "expect `from` to be formatted correctly" do
     expect( @email.header['From'].to_s ).to eq("Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>")
  end

  it "expect `reply_to` to be formatted correctly" do
     expect( @email.header['Reply-To'].to_s ).to eq("Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>")
  end

  it "expect `to` to be formatted correctly" do
     expect( @email.header['To'].to_s ).to eq("Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>")
  end
end
```

Comment: Still required in Rails5. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

*** Update:

The square brackets you're getting indicate that you're receiving an array.  So you need to extract the values out of the array to verify their validity.  The reason for this is that you could have multiple addressees, so for example the object could return:
["Aaron Test ", "Renoir "]

---

As far as I understand, you don't need to use the square brackets, and you don't need to include the quote marks in the string.

These should work:

```
from: "Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>",
reply_to: "Aaron Test <aaron@test.com>"
```

Comment: I agree, that should work. I tried 3 different ways and the test results are the same. I am guessing there is a different method I need to test against. Perhaps rendering the email view and parse the header.

Comment: no that doesn't work. I posted an answer that shows how to test the header values.